# How to make my own web app

Tags: webapps

After switching to Ubuntu 12.10, I have discovered I like the Web App's feature. I do not, however, like the Gwibber application, or [Twitter.com](http://twitter.com/) (and it's web app) because of lack of features.

I do, however, like the Twitter client [Hotot](http://hotot.org/), but for some reason, is not working for me right now.

I was wondering if there was a way I could make [web.tweetdeck.com](http://web.tweetdeck.com/) a Web App, until I can get [Hotot](http://hotot.org/) working for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your problem with Hotot the same than mine ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/205222/white-screen-for-hotot-in-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: Yes. I didn't know about the terminal part, but the rest of it is the same

Answer (score 1):

Over the coming weeks we should see a better system for creation and submission of new webapps.

In the mean time!

First start would be to check out lp:webapps-applications repo you can look for example in src/Twitter. You will need to write a manifest.json, and a .user.js.

If you end up writing the script, please merge propose to lp:webapps-applications, then we could throw it in to the packaging system for everyone!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry for not responding until now. I now have more questions for you. A.) How do I look at/download the example at src/Twitter in the `lp:webapps-applications` repo? Is there some sort of tutorial on how to make web apps? Because I am a noob, but want to learn how to do these things.