# White screen for Hotot in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, gtk, twitter, hotot

I have got a problem when I use Hotot on Ubuntu 12.10 (GTK version). When I want to authorize Hotot to use my Twitter account, it displays me a white screen. I an it in a terminal and it displays this mesage when the white screen appears :

```
** (hotot:8575): WARNING **: Binding '<Alt>C' failed!
```

So how to solve this problem ? How to do to avoid this white screen ?

**EDIT** : it seems to be related to this bug : [Bug #1019752 "hotot won't start correctly xubuntu 12.10"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hotot/+bug/1019752)

**EDIT 2** : [this bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hotot/+bug/1019752/comments/5) explains how to work around the problem.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I did it with launchpad.net (I have got an account) and it has already been reported here : [Bug #1019752 "hotot won't start correctly xubuntu 12.10"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hotot/+bug/1019752). The difference is that I use Ubuntu instead of Xubuntu.

Comment: You'll want to put that in the bug report then!